# Cassandra system.log file does not exist or is in another directory

Tags: cassandra

I kept reinstalling cassandra several times and still get the problem following the installation guide in the official website, after executing this command tail -f logs/system.log I got this result:
tail: cannot open 'logs/system.log' for reading: No such file or directory
tail: no files remaining
Please help me solve this problem

I searched for the system log and cannot find it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're following the tarball instructions here: [Installing Cassandra](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/installing/installing.html)

In the instructions, some of the commands are doubled-up. Example; changing into the Cassandra directory and starting it in one step:

```
cd apache-cassandra-4.0.0/ && bin/cassandra
```

I highly recommend breaking these up, and running them one at a time.

Note that until Cassandra starts, the `logs` directory will not exist. I suspect that is what is happening here, where Cassandra doesn't start and therefore the logs directory does not exist.

Assuming that you have already downloaded Cassandra 4.1.3, first untar the archive:

```
tar xzvf apache-cassandra-4.1.3-bin.tar.gz
```

Next, change into the newly-created directory:

```
cd apache-cassandra-4.1.3
```

To start Cassandra, I recommend using the `-p` option to specify a PID (process identifier) file:

```
bin/cassandra -p cassandra.pid
```

Starting Cassandra with a PID file also lets it run in the background. Otherwise, any keypress after running `bin/cassandra` on its own, will kill the process.

If Cassandra starts, you should see this as the last line on the terminal:

```
INFO  [main] 2023-12-18 08:42:05,540 StorageService.java:2922 - Node localhost/127.0.0.1:7000 state jump to NORMAL
```

At this point, running a `tail -f logs/system.log` should work just fine.

Go through these steps, and edit your post with any errors that you may see when running `bin/cassandra -p cassandra.pid`.